# How to perform text search on datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

May I know, how can I perform search on this default `DataGrid`? While added the value on it.

```
<DataGrid Name="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Background="White">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding StartDate}" SortDirection="Descending" SortMemberPath="StartDate" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Tag}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: someyhing like this http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2009/08/27/wpf-datagrid-search-and-highlight.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to Create and Use a CollectionView**

The following example shows you how to create a collection view and bind it to a ListBox **In the same way you can use it with datagrid**

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Customers} />
</Window>

public class CustomerView
{
   public CustomerView()
   {
        DataContext = new CustomerViewModel();
   }
}


public class CustomerViewModel
{
    private ICollectionView _customerView;

    public ICollectionView Customers
    {
        get { return _customerView; }
    }

    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        IList<Customer> customers = GetCustomers();
        _customerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(customers);
    }
}
```

**Filtering**

To filter a collection view you can define a callback method that determines if the item should be part of the view or not. That method should have the following signature: bool Filter(object item). Now set the delegate of that method to the Filter property of the CollectionView and you're done.

```
ICollectionView _customerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(customers);
_customerView.Filter = CustomerFilter

private bool CustomerFilter(object item)
{
    Customer customer = item as Customer;
    return customer.Name.Contains( _filterString );
}
```

**Refresh the filter**

If you change the filter criteria and you want to refresh the view, you have to call Refresh() on the collection view

```
public string FilterString
{
  get { return _filterString; }
  set 
  { 
      _filterString = value; 
      NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");
      _customerView.Refresh();
  }
}
```